# Can I use Scheduler HTTP API with minimesos?

Tags: cluster-computing, mesos, minimesos

I'd like to program a Mesos framework and test it against Minimesos. For the framework I'd like to use the HTTP API, but I can't find any evidence that Minimesos accepts it.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

---

Mesos HTTP API appeared as a stable in 1.0.0 which is available in Minimesos so you can use Scheduler with HTTP API.

https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/minimesos/blob/a8621043cfdfb3bfc2cecf59e89bc4ed48cf676e/Makefile#L8-L9

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers. Yes, should be supported and you can also see it here:

https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/minimesos/blob/master/minimesos/src/main/groovy/com/containersol/minimesos/config/MesosContainerConfig.groovy